# How to create a new Java + Maven + Spring + Hibernate/JPA project from scratch with Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven

I'm using Eclipse (Neon.1) and Java 8.  I know my way around Java and in the past I created Java projects by File > New > Java Project (for a POJO project).  Or File > New > Dynamic Web Project (for a WAR web app project).

But today I want a project that uses Maven, Spring MVC, Spring ORM, JPA/Hibernate, and probably a couple of other things.

I'm confused about how to build this project in Eclipse.

Do I do File > New > Java Project ... and tweak it and add stuff to it?

Or do I File > New > Maven Project ... and tweak it and add stuff to it?

I've also heard that Spring Boot is a good way to get started with this kind of thing.

Any pointers or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Spring Tool Suite IDE is good choice when using Spring

Comment: How I miss the good old time when tools were simple and programming was all about programming.

Comment: If you are just starting to learn web programming with Java, leave all these frameworks alone and start with Servlet. Assuming you know the basics about web already.

Comment: @smwikipedia Hi, I'm not new to Java programming, it's just been a few years since I built a project from scratch in Eclipse, and I know a "Java Project" and "Dynamic Web Project" isn't the way it's done anymore.  Thx.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you use spring boot. It's very easy to develop Spring Based applications with Java. It avoids writing lots of boilerplate code, Annotations and XML Configuration.

here's the link on how to use spring boot with maven. 
https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/

Comment: You can also generate your pom and dependencies by using spring-boot initializr https://start.spring.io/

Comment: Hi! @AlexCiocan I have generated my spring project from this site http://start.spring.io/ (spring boot, srping data jpa, spring security and spring mvc). Now I want to add angular and bower to my project. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is probably using the [Spring Initializr](http://start.spring.io/); That web interface is also provided in IDEs (cannot speak to how it's implemented in Eclipse though).

What you'll get is `pom.xml` file that you then can use to create a new maven project by pom file. It will load all the dependencies you choose and makes configuration simple.

Answer (score 1):

I usually create a Maven Project and add any Stuff like Spring MVC, Hibernate to it. And Spring boot is highly recommended, no need to look at xml files anymore. Here is a archetype that may useful:
https://github.com/superalsrk/cn.stackbox.archetypes

Answer (score 1):

Let me explan one by one.

- java - programming language
- Maven - Build tool and dependencies manager like npm or bower
- Spring - A java framework witten top of java also contains java codes
- Hibernate/JPA - is another framework in java helps to handle data access and store data in database

In eclipse You need to create a maven project which will creates the project structure. it will create a pom.xml file and then you need to add spring and jpa related dependencies.

Then maven will manage those dependencies and now you can write your programming logic to manage your data and UI.

You can refer [sample project in git](https://github.com/aniruddhadas9/google-appenigne-spring-jpa-eclipse-sample)

Answer (score 1):

You can install the `m2e` plugins (usually come along with eclipse already). And configure it according to your local `maven` installation.

And then create a web application skeleton based on the maven project templates/archetypes provided by the m2e plugin like the normal new project process.

And then you can edit the `pom.xml` file (Project Object Model, which is the maven project file) to include the packages you need, such as Spring, etc.

I don't have my dev machine at hand. So the above descriptions may be vague without proper screenshots. So please follow the below 2 quick guides. Hope they help.

- https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html
- https://web.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/m2e-liferay+Quick+Start+Tutorial

And these:

[Using Maven within the Eclipse IDE - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseMaven/article.html)

[Maven + Spring hello world example](https://www.mkyong.com/spring/quick-start-maven-spring-example/)

Answer (score 1):

Some examples related for requested technology stack:

Jersey + Spring example: https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jersey-spring-integration-example/

Jersey + Hibernate + Spring example: http://www.benchresources.net/jersey-2-x-web-service-integrating-with-spring-and-hibernate-orm-framework-using-annotation/

As chaixxiv mentioned previously https://stackoverflow.com/a/40966438/5962766, to avoid boilerplate code you can use Spring Boot. More samples:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/